# How to redirect from AREA's cshtml page to normal controller's ActionResult using @Url.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas, url.action

How can I redirect to an ActionResult of a normal controller from .cshtml page of my Area's view?

I have a common login screen for normal/admin user.
So based on the usertype json result will return the user type.
So now I want to redirect a user based on the usertype.

If a user is normal user then I can redirect him using 
`"var redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';"` and then `"window.location.href = redirectUrl;"`
Above code is working fine.

But what to do in following case?
If a user is an admin, then I want to redirect him to "Index" ActionResult of "HomeController" which is present in "Admin" area.

Answer (score 4):

To redirect outside the area use a blank string for the area:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })
```

This will default you back to the `HomeController` outside of the area.

Comment: @hutchnoid @NightOwl888 : Thanks

Finally below syntax worked for me.

`var adminHomePageUrl = '@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area = "Admin" })';`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need some conditional logic on your link.

```
@{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })

    if (this.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
    {
        redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" })
    }
}

<script>
    var redirectUrl = '@redirectUrl';
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
</script>
```

Although, a better alternative might be to make your own [HTML helper extension method](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) so you can reuse the logic elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Finally below syntax worked for me.

`var adminHomePageUrl = '@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area = "Admin" })';`